# how to update amazon linux gmp package?

Tags: package-management, amazon-linux, amazon

We have an Amazon Linux server and we scan it using OpenVAS. It detected one high vulnerability which is **Amazon Linux Local Check: alas-2016-754**.
Looking at the solution it says **Run yum update php70 to update your system.**
The vulnerable package detected is:
Vulnerable package: gmp
Installed version:  gmp-6.0.0-11.16.amzn1
Fixed version:      gmp-7.0.11-1.16.amzn1

At first we don't have php installed. So what we did is install latest version of php. Upon running the suggested solution the result is "No packages marked for update".
We also did yum update.

After doing another scan the package is still detected by OpenVAS.
The question is how to update this package?

Comment: An art of vulnerability scanning is watching out for false positives.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the `php70-gmp` package that is missing. Could you try `yum -y install php70-gmp` and rerun the OpenVAS scan?

Comment: I find it weird that you’d have to *install* more software in this scenario. Or is OpenVAS that broken?

Comment: @StephenKitt True, but given the specific issue (https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2016-754.html) and the advice given by OpenVAS, it could be a false positive that OpenVAS detects. In AL1, there is only `gmp-6.0.0-11.16.amzn1.x86_64` in base. In AL2, there is `gmp-6.0.0-15.amzn2.0.2.x86_64`. I thought that installing `php70-gmp` might "resolve" the OpenVAS issue, albeit ugly, and fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I’m not saying your answer is wrong, just that it’s rather unfortunate that it is a possible solution. (So it’s not a reflection on your answer, but rather on the state of security auditing tools.)

Comment: @Edward if the quality of detection by OpenVAS is 97% would it still be considered as false positive?

Comment: Well that's an academic discussion of course. Every detected vulnerability that's not actually a vulnerability is a false positive, regardless of the percentage true positives. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity for a nice writeup on this. BTW: did the "fix" work?

Comment: @Edward Thanks for the article. 
We did your suggested fix but it didn't work.

Comment: That's too bad. Maybe you could open support tickets with OpenVAS and/or AWS to get them to look at this probable false positive.

Comment: @Edward will do. We also installed php70-gmp.x86_64 but OpenVAS still detected the same vulnerability. Thanks for the help though.